# Extremely slow access of nfs nas on raspbian by Ubuntu

Tags: raspberrypi, nfs, nas, plex

I have my NFS NAS set up on an RPi 4, 4gb with external drives of WD SSD in a powered enclosure formatted ext4.  I am using Ubuntu as my Plex server accessing that NAS RPi 4, 4gb also.

I correctly add it to /etc/exports (as are others) and run sudo exportfs -ar.  I see the Ubuntu server in showmount -e xxx.xxx.x.xxx.  I mount it and just doing cd and ls are painfully slow.  I am also using a raspbian server to access the NAS in the same way which is lightening fast as I would expect.  This would seem to be simply solved.  What could I be doing wrong?

I would think that using Ubuntu and Raspbian together as NAS server/client would work fine.  I have many, many other Raspbian servers acting as NAS clients just fine.  I am trying Ubuntu as my Plex server because a Raspbian server for hosting Plex does not seem to recognize all videos, even with mediainfo.

Comment: How do you mount the drives on the Pi, and how do you mount them on Ubuntu? Are these one-off `mount` commands in terminal or are they made permanent in `/etc/fstab`? What mount options do you use for each?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that mounting with `sync` option makes things _very_ slow. Only `async` is speedy.